# MySQL - search for duplicates from gravity forms database

Tags: mysql, duplicates, gravityforms

I need an SQL query from a gravity form to search for duplicate entries.
Gravity form save entries in rows and I must change it to columns.

The default query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `value` DESC
```

[look at screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbAgh.jpg)

I don't know if this is a good solution but in works for me:

```
SELECT id, lead_id, form_id,
MAX(case when field_number = 6 then value end) Projektname, 
MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) Projektnummer, 
MAX(case when field_number = 129 then value end) Keyaccounter
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` GROUP BY lead_id
HAVING form_id = 1
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5L3A.jpg)

But now I must serach for duplicates in field_numer 7 to list only entries who have duplicates in this field. I have change the last line with this:

```
HAVING form_id = 1 AND HAVING COUNT(field_number = 7) > 1
```

This does not work.

Comment: what doesn't work? What's the error? Usually there's only one having condition. Try: HAVING form_id = 1 AND COUNT(field_number = 7) > 1

Comment: With my code I get an syntax error. Your code get no error but also no result of count. All entries will be displayed.

Comment: Ok I make a test and count field 7. The result in my 5 rows: 67, 68, 56, 57, 56. Therefore COUNT(field_number = 7) > 1 will list all rows. but I do not understand where these numbers come from?